# Refresh tkinter label automatically not on button press

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi there i am building a short game in tkinter and would like to be able to output to the user via a label within my tkinter window. I have looked at past questions and found no help apart from getting it to refresh using a button which is not what i want it to do. In short i need to have it refresh everytime a variable is changed.

My code :

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
w = 800 # width for the Tk root
h = 500 # height for the Tk root
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
wheat=10
money=0
title=tk.Label(root, text="The Farm Game")
title.config(font=('times', 20, 'bold'))
title.place(height=30, width=300, x = 250 , y = 10)


def advance():
    moneyguidisplay = tk.StringVar()
    moneyshowed = ("£", money)
    moneyguidisplay.set(moneyshowed)
    moneygui = tk.Label(root, wraplength=200, textvariable=moneyguidisplay)
    moneygui.config(bg='lightgreen', font=('times', 15, 'bold'))
    moneygui.place(height=30, width=200, x=600, y=60)
    Usershow = tk.StringVar()
    shownow = ("Welcome to The farm game")
    Usershow.set(shownow)
    USER = tk.Label(root, wraplength=200, textvariable=Usershow)
    USER.config(bg='lightpink', font=('times', 15, 'bold'))
    USER.place(height=200, width=400, x=200, y=100)
    wheatguidisplay = tk.StringVar()
    wheatshowed = ("Wheat:", wheat)
    wheatguidisplay.set(wheatshowed)
    Wheatgui = tk.Label(root, wraplength=200, textvariable=wheatguidisplay)
    Wheatgui.config(bg='lightblue', font=('times', 15, 'bold'))
    Wheatgui.place(height=30, width=200, x=0, y=60)
    root.after(100, advance)

root.after(100, advance)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What label are you asking about? What help do you need? It appears you know about the `after` and `configure` methods, which is about all you need to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but what I can understand is that you want to be able to change the text of a Label, depending on the value of another variable(correct me if I'm wrong). You can use the config method to do so. I have written a small function for it, you can put it in your program.

```
from tkinter import*

root=Tk()

L=Label(text="Label text changing after 5 sec")
L.grid()

# Call this function where the value of your variable/number changes
def ChangeValue(num):
    L.config(text=str(num))
    print("Value Changed")
root.update()
root.after(5000,lambda :ChangeValue("Text Changed!"))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was playing around with the after method and couldn’t get my head round it. Thanks

Comment: Please accept my answer if it was helpful. Happy to help! : )

Comment: hi there again i am implanting it into my code and am struggling to figure how to call a change in the label text not based on time but when i call it within my program may you explain ?

Comment: So, you don't want a delay but, you want a change of the label text (correct me if I'm wrong)?
Just call this function from anywhere inside your code, like any other normal function. Just take care that the label that you are changing is defined in the scope (where you call the function).